# Unable to create an object of type 'DbContext'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I try to run

```
dotnet ef migration add Init
```

I get error

> Unable to create an object of type 'IdentityContext'.

I know what caused the problem. I wanted to learn using message bus and added it to my project, so I run for some course and implemented it. Ofc bus working perfectly. But the problem is that I can no longer migrate via EF.

My Startup.cs before was.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Now it looks like this.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ServiceHost.Create<Startup>(args)
    .UseRabbitMq()
    .Build()
    .Run();
}
```

And ServiceHost class

```
public void Run() => _webHost.Run();

public static HostBuilder Create<TStartup>(string[] args) where TStartup : class
{
  Console.Title = typeof(TStartup).Namespace;
  var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();
  var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseStartup<TStartup>();

  return new HostBuilder(webHostBuilder.Build());
}
```

So anyone would give advice why migration stopped to work? For me it looks like it should work, but it isn't so I guess I'm wrong.

And ofc I have in my Startup.cs

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")));
```

EDIT
IdentityContext class:

```
  public class IdentityContext : DbContext
  {
    public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options) : base(options)
    {
      while (!Debugger.IsAttached)
      {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
      }
    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasIndex(user => user.Email).IsUnique();
      modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasIndex(user => user.Username).IsUnique();
    }
  }
```

EDIT2.
Verbose migration

```
Using project '/home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/CrossX.Identity.csproj'.
Using startup project '/home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/CrossX.Identity.csproj'.
Writing '/home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/obj/CrossX.Identity.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=/tmp/tmpCq3PQa.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo /home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/CrossX.Identity.csproj
Writing '/home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/obj/CrossX.Identity.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=/tmp/tmpR48yu8.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo /home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/CrossX.Identity.csproj
dotnet build /home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/CrossX.Identity.csproj /verbosity:quiet /nologo

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.17
dotnet exec --depsfile /home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/CrossX.Identity.deps.json --additionalprobingpath /home/msek/.nuget/packages --runtimeconfig /home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/CrossX.Identity.runtimeconfig.json /home/msek/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-ef/2.2.2/dotnet-ef/2.2.2/tools/netcoreapp2.2/any/tools/netcoreapp2.0/any/ef.dll migrations add Init --assembly /home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/CrossX.Identity.dll --startup-assembly /home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/CrossX.Identity.dll --project-dir /home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/ --language C# --working-dir /home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity --verbose --root-namespace CrossX.Identity
Using assembly 'CrossX.Identity'.
Using startup assembly 'CrossX.Identity'.
Using application base '/home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2'.
Using working directory '/home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity'.
Using root namespace 'CrossX.Identity'.
Using project directory '/home/msek/Projects/inz/CrossX/src/CrossX.Identity/'.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding IWebHost accessor...
No CreateWebHostBuilder(string[]) method was found on type 'CrossX.Identity.Program'.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'IdentityContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'IdentityContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 ---> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass12_3.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass12_3.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to create an object of type 'IdentityContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Comment: I've always registered the db context using postgres like this:
```services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")));```
Could you try and check if it works?

Comment: Same error. Unable to create an object of type 'IdentityContext'.

Comment: Did you debug and check that the startup class is being called properly?

Comment: What if you change this:

 ```var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseStartup<TStartup>();

  return new HostBuilder(webHostBuilder.Build());
``` 
for 

```return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseStartup<TStartup>();```

Comment: @carloschourio I debugged, and dont see any problems.

Comment: @carloschourio Cannot convert expression type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder' to return type 'CrossX.Common.Services.ServiceHost.HostBuilder'

Comment: Had the same problem. Was because I was running the CLI-command from solution-folder, if so startup-project must be defined:

```dotnet ef migrations add mymigration --startup-project .\Project-With-Startup.cs --project .\Project-With-Context --context MyContext```

Answer (score 95):

If you are using the CLI,

When you have a solution with 2 projects API/WebApp and a DataAcess project you can pass in the options on the command line.

```
My_Solution
       |DataAccess_Project
       |-- DbContext.cs
       |WebApp_Project
       |-- Startup.cs
```

**Change into the solution directory**

```
CD My_Solution
```

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project DataAccess_Project --startup-project WebApp_Project
```

```
dotnet ef database update --project DataAccess_Project --startup-project WebApp_Project
```

Comment: Thank you, backwards though.  First one should read `dotnet ef migrations add....`

Comment: @screamin Thanks for explaining the case of a Solution having multiple projects. You saved my day 

Comment: Also from .NET 5 and up, it will be "Program.cs" instead of "Startup.cs". Just mentioning here to avoid confusion for those who are facing this issue now.

Comment: this one solved my problem! thanks!

Comment: This is also useful if you have multiple DbContexts in multiple projects. `dotnet ef database update --context FinanceDbContext --project Finance.Data --startup-project MyApplication`

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tested on VS Code on linux. it works!

Answer (score 34):

My problem was that I didn't set my api project from the solution as Startup Project so it wouldn't find any Startup.cs or sth like that.

Comment: You sir, are a bloody ledged :)

Comment: Also set the Default Project to the Data project in the Package Manager Console, this helped me

Comment: You are correct! If in layered architecture, you must select the project that has the DBContext at the Package Manager Console (has @Ivan Yurchenko said) AND the project that has the "AddDbContext" method must be set as Startup Project (has you said).

Answer (score 32):

Make sure you have default constructor of IdentityContext  without parameters. It should work.

Comment: Deceptively simple, but I regularly forget about this (usually passing in options to the only constructor).

Comment: Surprised to find that a constructor with defaulted parameter doesn't count as a parameterless constructor. This did not work:        public HumbleDbContext(string connectionString = "Server=.;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;")

Answer (score 8):

Seems like you implemented IdentityContext but somewhere in your app its still trying to reference DbContext. Make sure Identitycontext is extending DbContext.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

EDIT: Implemented IDesignTimeDbContextFactory as stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation

Comment: I attached IdentityContext class. Its extending DbContext. And as I said it worked before I changed Startup.cs so I assume is correctly implemented. At last in this part.

Comment: I see in the old startup you were passing the args to CreateWebHostBuilder and in the ServiceHost you are not passing it.

Comment: which dot net core version are you using?

Comment: # dotnet --version
# 2.2.105

Comment: run add-migration initial -verbose and see what underlying error it gives

Comment: Attached verbose migration.

Comment: Try implementing IDesignTimeDbContextFactory as stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation or https://codingblast.com/entityframework-core-idesigntimedbcontextfactory/

Comment: it was solution. At least it seems to be :) It created table and connected to db. I wonder why that happen. I will need to dig into it.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using the new .NET 5 top-level code feature, then it is definitely why the migration is breaking. Using top-level statements in the `Program` class makes it impossible for the EF Tools to access it as it includes neither a namespace nor a class name.

Top-level statements:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Classic `Program` class:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

If this is the case, then just go back to the classic pattern.

Comment: Thanks, saved me lot of time! :d

Answer (score 6):

Create a method in the Program class named **CreateWebHostBuilder**. Move your main method body to that class and call that class from the Main method. New implementation would be:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    ServiceHost.Create<Startup>(args)
                .UseRabbitMq()
                .Build()
                .Run();
```

ef tool looks around CreateWebHostBuilder method and returns error when failed to find any.

Answer (score 6):

**Improving screamin's answer**

I have a project structure like below

Solution

- X.Api
- ...
- ...
- X.Repository

My migrations are under X.Repository and my startup project is X.Api. After setting everything decently, without any code errors, I could not run my migrations using the command below

```
dotnet ef migrations add CreateABCTable
```

Applying the solution screamin suggested, I could run my migrations. I have used the command below

```
dotnet ef migrations add CreateABCTable --project X.Repository.csproj --startup-project ../X.Api/X.Api.csproj
```

Comment: Thanks I had a project structure like you and this makes the ef migration bundle command works

Comment: Same for me, I had to run that second command specifying the project where I wanted to target my dbContext and the also give the argument for the startup proj...

Answer (score 3):

Adding this variant of a solution in case it helps someone. I needed to create a migration in a simple console app and had to add an empty default .ctor to the DbContext class.

```
public TestContext()
{
}

public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```

Comment: this solved it for me, I thought it was trying to re-create my context class but it was actually trying to instantiate it.

Answer (score 3):

it's probably giving to you this problem, because you are using layered architecture. so you must factory desing pattern .for examlpe your context class must be like this below ;

```
     public ModelContext(DbContextOptions<ModelContext> options) : base(options){}

       public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ModelContext>
    {

                DbContextOptionsBuilder<ModelContext> builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ModelContext>();               
                IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"C:/Users/mücteba/source/repos/market/Market.API")) 
                       
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
           builder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("SQLProvider"));
            return new ModelContext(builder.Options);
     }
  }
      DbSet<Personel> personels { get; set; }
```

this class is required if you use layered architecture!!!!

Comment: This was my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just move your dbcontext config before builder.Build()

builder.Services.AddDbContext(options =>
options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

var app = builder.Build();

Answer (score 1):

EF needs to be able to get an instance of DbContext.

From [an answer here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2143832.aspx?EF%20Core%20Migration%20error%20Unable%20to%20create%20an%20object%20of%20type%20ApplicationContext%20):

> Make sure you **set the default startup project to the WebApplication**.
> Then in the Package Manager Console **set the Default Project to the
> Data project**.  This will use the WebApplication configuration and add
> migrations to the Data project.

If you're running update-database command then you'll need to set the default project to your WebAPI project where the Startup.cs file is located.

Answer (score 1):

In your classes using `DbContext` set the constructor like:

```cs
public class NameContext: DbContext
{
    public NameContext(DbContextOptions<NameContext> options) : base(options)
    { }
}
```

Resource:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

Answer (score 1):

Just to add current info in case it helps someone on .Net 6.
In my case using .Net 6, and dotnet-ef version '6.0.4' the single key thing that made it work was ensuring the no-params constructor was present and public as in:

```
public TestContext()
{
}
```

My problem was that VS Code had created a protected constructor for me.
Some things that I tried that made NO difference:-

- if your console app uses top-level statements or not,
- NO need to have a `TestContext(options)` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In Program.cs, I called builder.Build() before builder.Services.AddDbContext
Just called builder.Build() at the end end it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error. but I was trying to do different operation. posting my experience hoping it will help someone.

initially got

```
dotnet ef migrations bundle
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'Di2Context'. For the different patterns `supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728`
```

then I ran `dotnet ef migrations bundle --verbose` to see fully detailed error.

In my solution there were several projects like Api, Domain, Infrastructure, Persistent etc.I was running this command inside Persistant project because it has the migration.cs files.

**When I moved inside Api project (which was my startup project) and ran**

```
dotnet ef migrations bundle --self-contained -r linux-x64
```

created the migration efbundle.exe without problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that Startup was not being detected in the way it was set in program:

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args, Type startup)
{
   return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup(startup);
}
```

passing the type directly solved the problem:

```cs
.UseStartup<Startup>()
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case the reason of issue was the incorrect path to the dbsettings.json file.
This path is should be written in the Startup.cs file.

```
 public Startup(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment hostEnv)
    {
        _confString = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(hostEnv.ContentRootPath).AddJsonFile("dbsettings.json").Build();
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this command in Package Manager Console and the problem was solved

dotnet-ef migrations add migrationName --context DBContext --project=MyProject.Data --startup-project=MyProject.Web -o Persistence\Migrations

'migrationName' is your migration name.
'MyProject.Data' is the layer that DBContext is in it.
'MyProject.Web' is your web project.

Answer (score 0):

Another check is to make sure the program runs in the first place. For unknown reasons if the program crashes EF migration builder won't notify you about it. So run the program on side to check if won't throw an exception right on the start.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by not being signed into your Microsoft account in Visual Studio. I've seen it many times. As soon as you re-enter your credentials, EF migrations will work fine. Also, make sure your startup project is set correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error.

The Entity Framework tools version '6.0.1' is older than that of the runtime '6.0.6'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.

I updated the package and it worked.