# Unable to create an object of type 'DbContext' while update database in .NET Core App using command Line

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, command-line, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have implemented ASP.NET Identity feature with code first approach in a .NET Core 6 project.
Here Migration is applied to create database and it's working fine with Visual Studio 2022.
But while running on VS Code using command **dotnet ef database update**, It's throwing below error:

[Error while update using command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VgsG.png)

The solution have 4 projects in it. Here Tutorial.API is the startup project and Tutorial.Data is the entity migration project. Below configuration is in program.cs of Tutorial.API project.

- Tutorial.API
- Tutorial.Core
- Tutorial.Data
- Tutorial.Repository

**Database configuration**

```cs
services.AddDbContext<SkyNetDBContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")));
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SkyNetDBContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I want to run update the database using command line

Comment: refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123853/unable-to-create-an-object-of-type-dbcontexts-name-for-the-different-patte)

Comment: This answer might help: [Unable to create an object of type 'DbContext'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69207083/4317797)